# Understanding the dd command in Linux

Tags: linux, dd

can someone explain to me what this command does:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=10MBfile1 count=10000 bs=1024
```

which produces this output:

```
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
10240000 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.146924 s, 69.7 MB/s
```

I couldn't make any sense of this, so could someone please explain to me what is happening and what it does. Thanks.

Comment: [Wikipedia dd](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) Also the first google result for **What is dd in linux?**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- it copies from /dev/zero, which is a special file that is a constant stream of zeros.
- it copies that to a file on disk, called '10MBfile1'
- it does it in blocks (think 'chunks') of 1024 bytes,
- and it does 10000 blocks, which is equal to 10MB.

So in summary, it makes a file on disk of 10MB which is filled with nothing but zeros on disk.

For example:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=blah count=10 bs=10
```

Makes a similar file called 'blah;, but only 100 bytes in size, and...

```
$hexdump blah
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000060 0000 0000
```

Shows that it's empty.

Answer (score 2):

The `dd` man page, at least on my current Debian Linux system, says for the synopsis "copy and convert a file."  That might be a bit confusing.

`dd`'s original purpose was to convert a file from IBM EBCDIC format into ASCII format.  It still does this if you specify the proper options, but unless you have a bunch of files from IBM mainframes laying around, you won't use it like that very much.

`dd` simply copies raw bytes from the input file (`if=`) to the output file (`of=`)  The number of bytes it will copy will be `bs=` times `count=`.

The (potentially very destructive) power of `dd` is that it does not care of the files specified are actual files, raw disk partitions (`/dev/sda1`), the entire raw disk device itself (`/dev/sda`), standard input or output, a tape drive, an MTD flash device, your system's CMOS (`/dev/nvram`), your graphics video memory (`/dev/fb0`), kernel memory (`/dev/kmem`), etc.  It just does it.

So, since your hard drive partition table lives on block 0 of your hard drive, and that the block is 512 bytes long, this will backup your hard drive partition table (and first stage bootloader) to a file:

`# dd if=/dev/sda of=sda.sector0.bin bs=512 count=1`

If you wanted to restore it for some reason, just reverse the `if=` and `of=` parameters.

If you don't specify `count=`, it will keep going until the end of device.  This will write zeros to your entire hard drive:

`# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`

So be careful.